# php: how to change string data become numeric data

Tags: php, mysql, string, numeric

can you tell how to change this result in php and mysql script:

```
  Model                  Class
Ball                        S
Book                        A
Spoon
Plate                       B
Box                         C
```

this is my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inspection_report` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Model` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `Serial_number` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Lot_no` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Line` char(5) NOT NULL,      
  `Class` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Model` (`Model`,`Serial_number`,`Lot_no`,`Line`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=48 ;
```

how if i want to show result like:

```
 Model           s       a       b       c
 Ball            1       0       0       0
 Book            0       1       0       0
 Spoon           0       0       0       0
 Plate           0       0       1       0
 Box             0       0       0       1
```

What's query to make this? thanks.

Comment: Do you want to tally all the results, or do you really only want to show 1 or 0. Please clarify your question a bit more. You do not say if you want the query result to be in this form or if it is fine to use php to reformat the result.

Comment: i'm just want show 1 or 0, like my example

Comment: What's the relation between Class and Model?

Comment: Class is defect condition of Model

Comment: Why do you need such an odd representation? Why your first table doesn't suit you?

Comment: And why the hell you want to alter your database design for this?

Comment: the reason why I should like this because if the character has changed into numbers, it will be a calculating. which if found in the field "s" number one or zero will be multiplied by 4. any better ideas?

Comment: When store your stupid conditions as numbers. And multiply whatever you want. There is no use of multiplying a zero though. It still remains a zero. And you still fail to explain a final goal. I doubt you understand it yourself

Comment: okey thanks..may be i will think another way to make this possible.

Comment: @Col: i found the answer. it come from Captaintokyo.

Comment: This is again just a part of the answer. Because you always ask a part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `Model`,
IF(`Class`='S', 1, 0) AS `S`,
IF(`Class`='A', 1, 0) AS `A`,
IF(`Class`='B', 1, 0) AS `B`,
IF(`Class`='C', 1, 0) AS `C`
FROM `inspection_report`
```

Comment: Thanks. Col. Shrapnel does have a point though. It remains unclear to me why you want/need this.

Comment: yups i thanks to you all.the reason why I should like this because if the character has changed into numbers, it will be a calculating. which if found in the field "s" number one or zero will be multiplied by 4.you know i'm going mad bcoz this problem about two weeks.fiuh.doumo arigatou gozaimasu.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm assuming you have the input data in an array mapping name to defect, and you want for each row a 1 in the appropriate column and a zero everywhere else. If so, it's just this:

```
$arr = array('blue' => 'S', 'red' => 'A', 'yellow' => null, 'green' => 'B', 'black' => 'C');

$defects = array_filter(array_unique(array_values($arr)));
echo "name\t";
echo implode("\t", $defects);
echo "\n";

foreach($arr as $name => $defect) {
    echo "$name";
    foreach($defects as $test) {
        echo "\t";
        echo $test == $defect ? 1 : 0;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why the quotes in `echo "$name"`?

Comment: @deceze It was originally `echo "$name\t";`; I changed it and didn't remove them

Comment: I see, it's just one of my pet peeves... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Very crude example, you'd probably go with HTML tables in reality.

```
<?php // $rows = array(array('name' => 'blue', 'class_defect' => 'S'), ...); ?>

<pre>
name      s  a  b  c
<?php
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    printf('%-10s', $row['name']);  // padding with spaces
    foreach (array('s', 'a', 'b', 'c') as $col) {
        echo (strtolower($row['class_defect']) == $col) ? 1 : 0;
        echo '  ';  // just padding again
    }
}
?>
</pre>
```