# send radiobutton's value to different fields at DB

Tags: php, database, radio-button, field, form-submit

i have a submit form that consist of 1 group radio button.

```
<div id="defectclass">
        <input id="def1" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="1"/>S
        <input id="def2" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="1" />A
        <input id="def3" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="1" />B
        <input id="def4" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="1" />C
</div>
```

beside that i have 4 fields at DB table, that is :

1. S
2. A
3. B
4. C

i want after submit:

```
    - if def1 are checked send value to field "S"
     - if def2 are checked send value to field "A"
     - if def3 are checked send value to field "B"
     - if def4 are checked send value to field "C"
     - if all not checked or null send to all fields value="0"
```

how do i do that bcoz i've never try this?

Comment: How are you handling the server side functionality? PHP, Python, C#?

Comment: does the row already exist? where are you inserting the row into the table?

Comment: Why don't you have just one field with possible values S, A,B,C?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: if have made just one field , but i have difficulty when i want to show this data field in another table. i must convert the data as you can see at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508812/php-how-to-change-string-data-become-numeric-data"

Comment: Well you are going to do a terrible mistake. Especially because the solution is very simple

Comment: What's the certain problem with these fields? Can you explain the whole story?

Comment: I was using only one field with a value SABC but I got into trouble for calling this data when I wanted to do something like that link. so I try another way, by doing this.

Comment: no, no, no! You will got into trouble if you store it in separate fields. And not a single problem with one. what kind of trouble you've got? what's table you're trying to link?

Comment: why the hell you put a link into quotes? I can't click it.  And I can't run over all your question looking for one you meant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508812/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508812/php-how-to-change-string-data-become-numeric-data. i dont do anything..whats problem?

Comment: Radio buttons cant be checked, they can be on/off . I think you might want to use checkboxes instead of radio buttons if you want to allow multiple fields to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to make just 1 field.
2. If you need numbers to represent these letters  make an **array**.

like this

```
$defects_arr = array(0,"S","A","B","C");
```

this array can be used in many tasks:

- to represent these letters with numbers
- to validate user rinput
- to build this input dynamically

So, upon receiving your POST data just compare it against this array:

```
$defect = '0';
if(!empty($_POST['defect'])) {
  $key = array_search($_POST['defect'],$defect_arr));
}
```

and you will have a number in the $key variable. This number should be stored in the database.

Comment: whether by doing this can answer my initial question on that link?

Comment: Hm, interesting solution, but I don't think this is what he is after. He wants 1 or 0, not 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: @klox this is not a question by the link but just a little bit of a question. A stub. But an array solution still lets to convert letters to numbers.

Comment: @captain he wants, but it's not what he really need

Comment: @Col.:can i use this for answer my link too?

Comment: @Col: can you answer at my link question, to prevent me become confuse bcoz of mixing question between this question and link question.

Answer (score -1):

By looking at the possible values of  `defect` , in your table definition,

change  `defect VARCHAR(1)`  to  `defect VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT "0"`

This simplifies your code to insert row/update columns

in your php script, after parsing the form, add a switch statement to decide which column to update.

```
// I assumed the row already exists

mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
@mysql_select_db ($database) or die("Error");

$defect = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["defect"]); //parse the defect field
$id = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST["id"]); //primary key of the table
$flag = True;

if(!empty($_POST['defect']))
{

   switch($defect)
   {
       case "S" : $var = "S";
                  break;
       case "A" : $var = "A";
                  break;
       case "B" : $var = "B";
                  break;
       case "C" : $var = "C";
                  break;
       default : $flag = False;
   }

   if($flag)
   {
      $query = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET" + $var + " = '1' WHERE Id = '$id'";
      mysql_query($query);
   }

   mysql_close(); 
}
```

Comment: When down voted, leaving a comment would help me correct myself.

Comment: Too much to correct. Not to mention this code is a sin against programming art - it repeats huge piece of code to change just ONE LETTER! And SQL injection as well.

Comment: No, because you only update one field. Suppose A = 1, now radio button S get selected. After executing your code both S and A will be 1, instead of only A.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="defectclass">
        <input id="def1" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect['s']" value="1"/>S
        <input id="def2" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect['a']" value="1" />A
        <input id="def3" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect['b']" value="1" />B
        <input id="def4" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect['c']" value="1" />C
</div>
```

This will give you $_POST['defect']['s'], &tc. so you'll know which update path to take. See http://php.net/faq.html for more about this syntax.

Comment: Any feedback on why the -1? It should be a perfectly acceptable solution to the problem as given?

Comment: it's not a solution at all. First of all it is not one radiobutton field but 4.