# php: how to change string data to numeric data

Tags: php, mysql, string, numeric

Can you tell how to change this string to numeric data in php and mysql script.

I need to insert data in a car_model_temp table based on user input.

This is the user input

```
Brand: Honda

carcolor: Black

transmission: Automatic

fuel: Petrol

Audio: Mp3
```

My query will check data in car_model table based on user input.

**car_model table**

```
Brand  carcolor   transmission   fuel      audio

Honda    Black      Automatic     Petrol    Mp3

Ford      Blue       Manual        Diesel    Dvd

Honda    Green      Automatic     Petrol    Dvd
```

How can I insert the data into car_model_temp after i check user input. I want to show result like this:

**car_model_temp**

```
Brand   carcolor   transmission   fuel      audio

1          1             1           1         1

0         0             0           0         0

1         0             1           1         0
```

Thanks.

Comment: please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508812/php-how-to-change-string-data-become-numeric-data

Answer (score 1):

One way to do a conversion like that is to use arrays. For example:

```
$color_ary = array("black", "white", "blue", ...);
```

Black will be the 0 element, white will be 1, blue = 2, etc.

So you can do your lookup on the array value and then get the array key for the numeric value to store in your db.

```
$color_val = array_search("Blue", $color_ary);
```

This will return the numeric value 2.

Answer (score 1):

### **SOLUTION 1**:

You can use switch case in php like this:

```
function to_number($input)
{
  switch($input)
  {
    case "Honda":
    case "Black":
    case "Automatic":
      return 0;
    case "Ford":
    case "Diesel":
    case "Dvd":
      return 1;
    default:
      return;
  }
}
```

and then pass the string as an argument to this function. [Control Structures - Switch case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
$num = to_number("string");
```

### **SOLUTION 2**:

You can also use [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in php like this:

```
$to_number = array(
             "Honda" => 0,
             "Black" => 0,
             "Automatic" => 0,
             "Ford" => 1,
             "Diesel" => 1,
             "Dvd" => 1,
);
```

and then can access the corresponding number for the string like this:

```
$num = $to_number[$string];
```

Answer (score 1):

use something similar to this in your select query

```
IF(`Brand  `='Honda', 1, 0) AS `Brand  `,
IF(`carcolor`='Black', 1, 0) AS `carcolor`,
```

kindly check this link for more details  **[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508812/php-how-to-change-string-data-become-numeric-data)**

Comment: something similar to this you can try